# Gulp error (module not found)

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have installed npm locally according to an article (I don't remember the URL). So that my npm packages are in `~/.npm-packages/`. So gulp is in `~/.npm-packages/bin/gulp` and this is a link: `gulp -> ../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js`

When I run `which gulp` I got `/home/victor/.npm-packages/bin/gulp`

When I go to the bin directory and run gulp like `./gulp.js -v` I can see it works. However, when I run gulp globally I got such error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/3.28.73.flags.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:25:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

So gulp is trying to find modules in /usr/lib, but why? Why not in my home directory? I have all these modules in `~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules`

I'm absolutely confused and can't get gulp working. I've tried to reinstall it with the same effect.

Comment: Do you have gulp installed locally in your project? You should only use the global package for the executable. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: I had the same issue, this helped: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/958

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I did to solve the problem:

1. **cd** /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags
2. **sudo node** fetch.js

And that's it. The last instruction will create the required file.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to solve the problem:

```
sudo npm install gulp && sudo npm install --save del && sudo gulp build
```